# Handle error in python

Tags: python, exception

I'm new to Python and I want to know the best way to handle the following error:

```
downloaded = raw_input("Introduce the file name: ").strip()
f, metadata = client.get_file_and_metadata('/'+downloaded)
#print 'metadata: ', metadata['mime_type']
out = open(downloaded, 'wb')
out.write(f.read())
out.close()
```

If I set a wrong name I get this error:

```
dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse: [404] u'File not found'
```

I could write a function to check if the file exists but I want to know If I can handle it in a better way.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: [Relevant discussion of EAFP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to try to open the file and if this fail, prompt the user to try again?

```
filefound = False
while not filefound:

    downloaded = raw_input("Introduce the file name: ").strip()
    try:
        f, metadata = client.get_file_and_metadata('/'+downloaded)
        #print 'metadata: ', metadata['mime_type']
        filefound = True
    except dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse as e:
        if e.status == 404:
            print("File " + downloaded + " not found, please try again")
            filefound = False
        else:
            raise e

out = open(downloaded, 'wb')
out.write(f.read())
out.close()
```

As pointed out by @SuperBiasedMan and @geckon, you are trying to call `client.get_file_and_metadata` and, if this fails with exception  `dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse`, handling this in some way. In this case the error handling code checks if the error is 404 (file missing) and tells the user to try a different file. As `filefound = False`, it results in another prompt to the user again. If the error is not file missing, the error is raised and the code stops.

Comment: Worth explaining that it's considered Pythonic to catch specific errors and deal with them rather than actually letting the program raise the errors.

Answer (score 0):

To append something to [Ed Smith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30243128/4408382), I would like to recommend you to read [something about exceptions and their handling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions) in general. You might know them from another languages like C++ or Java as well, but if you're new to programming, you should know about the concept and it's advantages.